# Как скрывать клавиатуру при нажатии вне её области?

Tags: java, android, клавиатура

Как скрывать клавиатуру при нажатии вне её области?

Comment: Она же сама скрывается при нажатии вне ее области?

Comment: @post_zeew нет, только при нажатии системной кнопки back,

Comment: Поэкспериментируйте: `Activity.onTouch()` вызывается при нажатии на клавиатуру? Если нет, то можно его использовать как индикатор нажатия вне области клавы

Answer (score 0):

добавьте в `OnClickListener` на какое то `View` вызов этого метода

```
    public static void hideSoftKeyboard(Activity activity) {
        if (activity != null) {
            InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) activity.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            if (inputMethodManager != null)
                if (activity.getCurrentFocus() != null)
                    if (activity.getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken() != null)
                        inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(activity.getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Ну а если я буду нажимать вне области но не view? тогда скрываться клавиатура не будет(

Comment: в не области не может быть чтоб не было места, где нет 'View'

Comment: вы знаете, что такое View? View - FrameLayout, ImageView, Button,...